# sendmail doesn't send email to specific domain email address

Tags: 12.04, email, sendmail

We have ubuntu 12.04 server and installed sendmail to send mails from this server.

**Problem:**

There is some strange issue on mail server. Somehow, server not able to send email to `xxx@ayolla.com`

but server sends email successfully to other email ids like `xxx@spaceotechnologies.com`, `xxx@gmail.com` or `xxx@yahoo.com`.

**Success Case: when send email to xxx@spaceotechnologies.com**

> Dec 28 11:40:49 ip-10-99-66-252 sm-mta[16954]: qBSBemdx016952:
>   to=, ctladdr=
>   (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120352,
>   relay=aspmx.l.google.com. [74.125.131.27], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK
>   1356694874 d3si34930711vdv.119) Dec 28 11:51:43 ip-10-99-66-252
>   sendmail[16960]: qBSBphki016960: from=www-data, size=89, class=0,
>   nrcpts=1, msgid=<201212281151.qBSBphki016960@ayolla.com>,
>   relay=www-data@localhost

**Fail Case: when send email to xxx@ayolla.com**

> Dec 28 11:51:43 ip-10-99-66-252 sm-mta[16962]: qBSBphSo016962:
>   ... User unknown Dec 28 11:51:43 ip-10-99-66-252
>   sendmail[16960]: qBSBphki016960: to=info@ayolla.com, ctladdr=www-data
>   (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30089,
>   relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown

Can someone please help to sort out this issue ?

Note: I don't want to expose our emails that's why i replaced xxx with original email address into this question.

Answer (score 0):

The user unknown message means `info` is not a valid user at the domain `ayolla.com`.

This is a permanent error and not something you can fix, as the email address (recipient) is rejected by this mail server.